# Adding Middleware in Bot Framework Composer V2

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I want to add a Middleware in a Bot Framework Composer project but I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

How would one go about adding a simple Middleware, let's say a Middleware that logs all the exchanged messages to console, in a bot created with Bot Framework Composer v2.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

you have to mention the middleware component name in "configure -> settings.json" file.
ex:

```
"components": [
  {
    "name": "BotComposerMiddlewareComponent"
  }
],
```

Note : BotComposerMiddlewareComponent is a middleware component
name.

find the sample here how to write the [custom middleware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfQ9zm7K0HI) for bot composer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class file
2. Inherit this interface - Microsoft.Bot.Builder.IMiddleware
3. Implement OnTurnAsync Method like below code sample
4. You will have access to context, Activity and other stuffs you do in bot framework library implementations

I have wrote a detailed article on creating middleware for Bot Framework Composer here:
https://www.lkgforit.com/2022/10/implementing-middleware-in-bot.html

Comment: The article link is broken. Do you have an updated link to your article?